# How can I decrypt a password stored in database and generated by the jhipster web-app?

Tags: jhipster

I have this in my application-dev.yml file:

```
security:
authentication:
  jwt:
    # This token must be encoded using Base64 and be at least 256 bits long (you can type `openssl rand -base64 64` on your command line to generate a 512 bits one)
    base64-secret: ODNiNWQ5NmY0M2ZiNTg3MDI1YjA2N2Y1OGVjMTY1ZWM3NzkxZTdlN2FiZGYyYzM2ZTljNTVkZGZiZmQzZDFlMTJhODNkMTEyNzM5NmY0MDMzZmI4Y2E2YjFkNzg1MDM2NzAwNDhhZDI1NGVjOGIyMDNlMGU3ZDZhNmQyZDk1YWY=
    # Token is valid 24 hours
    token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
    token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
```

and I want to decrypt one of the user passwords stored in the postgres database, for example: `$2a$10$j8S5d7Sr7.8VTOYNviDPOeWX8KcYILUVJBsYV83Y5NtECayypx9lO` How can I do it?

Comment: Your JWT secret has nothing to do with your password storage. More importantly, though, **why** do you want us to help you decrypt user passwords?

Comment: In case I forget one password, how can I recover it?

Comment: You can send a reset request: `https://your-domain/account/reset/request`

Comment: You can't decrypt passwords, they are hashed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot decrypt password hashes, they are encrypted using 10 rounds [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (Spring Framework default configuration). The JWT secret has nothing to do with password encryption.

If a user has lost his password he should request a password reset and will receive a reset link by email.

If the problem is that you have lost the password for a user in your development environment it could be faster to just encrypt a new password using the same 10-rounds Bcrypt algorithm (this can even be done online) and replace the `password_hash` in the database directly.

Also, please generate a new `base64-secret` key and do not share it with anyone as instructed in the [jhipster documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#securing-jwt).

Comment: you get a plus one because you also informed the OP that they shouldn't have releaved their base64 secret.

Comment: Very useful information, but how can I conifgure the email service in my web app?

Comment: You can configure the email server in your `application-*.yml` files (`application-prod.yml` for production) under `spring.mail`. If you have a specific problem with that maybe it would be better to create a new question :)